# How to edit a long post?

Tags: discussion, editing, edit-history

Sometimes I spend around 5 minutes editing some post, correcting TeX commands, etc. But when I submit my edit I discover that somebody already did another one.

But sometimes his edit is not so complete as mine and even so my edit does not appear.

How to avoid this kind of wast of time?

Comment: There usually is a live notification when someone is editing your post simultaneously.

Comment: @Tim, but in this case what should I do? Stop editing or not? What happens if I go on and submit my edit?

Comment: Make a copy of your current revision. See the updated version immediately. You won't lose your original one, because you can always check the edit history.

Comment: When I get that notification when I try to post my edit, I copy my edit to the clipboard, and take a look at the updated post; if it still needs work, I can simply paste in my edit. If I get the notification before I’m done, I finish my edit and proceed as in the other case.